# GCC 5.3 failing in the make phase

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, ubuntu-16.04

Currently I have GCC 5.4.0-6 installed on my Ubuntu 16.04.4 machine. However nvcc wants me to use 5.3, so I am trying to install that version as well. I did this by:
1. downloading `gcc-5.3.0.tar.gz`
2. extracting it to `~/Documents/libraryDownloads/GCC-5/gcc-5.3.0`
3. creating the folder `~/Documents/libraryDownloads/GCC-5/gcc-build`
4. In `~/Documents/libraryDownloads/GCC-5/gcc-5.3.0` I used the command   `./contrib/download_prerequisites`.
5. In `~/Documents/libraryDownloads/GCC-5/gcc-build` I used the command `./../gcc-5.3.0/configure --enable-multilib`
6. and finally in `~/Documents/libraryDownloads/GCC-5/gcc-build` I used the command `make`

The make-process rand for a short while and then ended with the following error:

```
checking whether the gcc  -m32 linker (ld -m elf_x86_64 -m elf_i386) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
Makefile:10699: recipe for target 'configure-stage1-zlib' failed
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-zlib] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myUser/Documents/libraryDownloads/GCC-5/gcc-build'
Makefile:22461: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myUser/Documents/libraryDownloads/GCC-5/gcc-build'
Makefile:902: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As far as I know, I have all prerequisites installed and I am doing all this in a separate build folder as recommended. I tried searching for `error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.`, but I couldn't find anyone with similar problems. Does anyone know what could be the cause of this error?

Comment: Have you solved it ? I have the same problem on debian 9, trying to build gcc 5 (i already have gcc 6)

Comment: I can't remember how I solved it, but checking my computer, I only have version 5.3.0 installed currently. My guess would be is that I uninstalled gcc and did a clean install of version 5.3.0. As far as I know I never solved the problem of running multiple version of gcc at the same time